# How to set height of Cell to Zero if Cell.textlabel.text is nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate event

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a situation where I want to set the hide the cell if cell.textlabel.text == nil.

I tried using heightForRowAtIndexPath...

But this event is fired before the cellForRowAtIndexPath event and that's why I doesn't get text of the cell.

Is there any way that I can set height of cell to zero if there cell.textlabel.text == nil in cellForRowAtIndexPath event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set values of TableView - the only way to change its appearance is to tell her to `reloadData`, and then let delegate feed it with new, fresh ones. You can also use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to remove a cell, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert it back later on.

From what you write I guess you structured your program in a very bad way. You should have a separation between Model, View and Controller.